# Creating multiple dropdown lists for one cell in google sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As always I like to fully disclose I'm not advanced at this stuff, so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a cell in google sheets have multiple dropdown lists depending on the selection of another cell?

I.e, IF C14 = [X] then I13 will = one drop down list. But if C14 = [Y] then I13 will = another dropdown list variation.

I was thinking the VLOOKUP tool but this doesn't seem to work. Would I need to create a script?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your own sheet, otherwise take a copy of https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IDifehV68cEGlI1pqpvNLEnReZRLnyiZf-4ipFl-E3s/copy

Comment: Thank you that worked!here is a link to a copy of my sheet: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k_65bawy-UvgYuffsp_2b1djDKvQqnngfTu7_0QR1Ac/copy

I'm trying to get F17 to set a calorie target depending on the dynamic drop down of I13. 

It works for the burning fat option which provides the deficits, but not for the build muscle option which provides the surplus. 

I've got the surplus to work in H17 for surplus, but was hoping there is a way to combine the two? 

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I called to get access to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Should be able to now? :)

Comment: F17, I13, H17 ... from wich sheet ? I am lost ! pls, create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sheet to determine which list should be applicable

Sheet `List`:

| List | List X | List Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| =ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Moderate Deficit'!I14="X",B2:B,IF('Moderate Deficit'!I14="Y",C2:C,))) | X1 | Y1 |
|  | X2 | Y2 |
|  |  | Y3 |

Set the drop-down list range to be from `List!A2:A`